# Why has the --group-directories-first switch for the ls command never evolved to have a short form as well?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, posix, coreutils

This has long puzzled me and this seemed like the best venue to solicit the perspective of those with far more POSIX time-in-grade than I have. I consider the parsing of `ls` output in this manner to be crucial and creating aliases to modify the `ls` command to default to it is always one of the first customizations I make to a new terminal profile.

Is this just an nasty side-effect of too many formative years spent using the Windows Explorer? Is there a mindset for interpreting the default mixed output that I've never heard explained, and once I do will have an epiphany with instant comprehension of why only cretins want directories and files separated? I know this is trivial but `ls` is such a touchstone for all command line activities that I feel as though I've missed something profound.

Thank you in advance for your teleological tutelage.

Comment: None of the long options are from POSIX; this is a GNU extension and many of those have no short option (including the surely more-common `--color`). I'm not sure anybody can tell you a reason why other than "nobody submitted the patch", though the supply of unused letters is running low (there are 26 single-character options required by POSIX right now, plus non-standard ones like `-h` that are universal in practice, and GNU has 40). A guessed heuristic might be "options that might be commonly modified for individual executions", but I have no basis for that other than the eye test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was discussed when the option was added to `ls`; [Jim Meyering said](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2006-04/msg00183.html)

> > Just one little question about this patch: are you sure not to add a
> >     short option for `--group-directories-first` ?
>
> For now, yes.  It would take a strong argument to go against the
>   “no new short option names” policy for `ls`, especially considering
>   the alternative mentioned below.
>
> > `--group-directories-first` is already in my `ls` aliases ;)
> >     but in this month I had to use other linuxes where those aliases were
> >     not defined, and I realized that typing `--group-directories-first` for
> >     such a useful feature is IMHO really annoying...
>
> Did you know that you can abbreviate that option with `--g`,
>   since there is no other long option name starting with `g`?

So basically, `ls` already has so many short options (which is itself a running joke in Unix circles) that it takes a really strong argument to add one, and `--group-directories-first` has a nice pseudo-short alternative.